# Increment JSON field in Mysql Json column results in float not integer

Tags: mysql, json

For some reason unknown to me, the below code I use to increment a json field converts it to a float and not an integer

```
UPDATE tags SET tag_meta = JSON_SET(IFNULL(tag_meta, 
    JSON_OBJECT('insert_count', 1)), '$.insert_count',
    IFNULL(tag_meta->>'$.insert_count', 0) + 1) WHERE tag_id = 123456789;
```

results in;

```
{"insert_count": 1.0}, {"insert_count": 2.0}... etc
```

and not

```
{"insert_count": 1}, {"insert_count": 2}
```

how to just keep it as integers?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works. Try it if you want.

```
 UPDATE table_name
 SET column_name= JSON_INSERT(column_name, '$.name', 'Jhon')
 WHERE id = 2
```

And look source link>>> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html

Comment: I have looked at the documentation but the result is the same. Also my goal is to increment a value or create it if it doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should care about NULL values and also casting types:

```
JSON_SET(COALESCE(`tag_meta`,'{}'), '$.fieldName',
        IF(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(tag_meta, '$.fieldName')) REGEXP ('^[0-9]+$'),
            JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(tag_meta, '$.fieldName')), 0) + 1)
```